# Mutually recursive traits in Rust with default implemenations

Tags: recursion, rust, traits

I would like to have a couple of traits with some default implementations (hard requirement), calling each other. Of course, a straightforward approach does not work, because trait A has trait B as a parent which has trait A as a parent... Turtles all the way down. What should I do? (I cannot join the traits together, they are supposed to be in different files.)

Non-working code, demonstrating the problem, would be

```
use std::fmt::Display;

trait A: B + Display {
    fn a(&self, count: i32) -> String {
        if count == 0 {
            String::new()
        } else {
            format!("[{}]a{}", self, self.b(count - 1))
        }
    }
}
impl A for String {}

trait B: A + Display {
    fn b(&self, count: i32) -> String {
        if count == 0 {
            String::new()
        } else {
            format!("[{}]b{}", self, self.a(count - 1))
        }
    }
}
impl B for String {}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", "Hello".to_string().a(3));
}
```

Comment: "Supposed to be in different files" sounds like a weak requirement. It's probably better to join them nevertheless.

Comment: It is a weak requirement. I will probably join them indeed, even though they are different conceptually. Calling each other seems to be enough of justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the actual end goal, then it can be easier to do what you're doing, by using auxiliary traits along with [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=blanket#blanket-implementation)s.

In short, instead of doing this:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("default foo");
    }
}

impl Foo for String {}
```

Then you introduce a `trait HasFoo` and use that to trigger a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=blanket#blanket-implementation) of `Foo`. Which would look something like this:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait HasFoo {}

impl<T> Foo for T
where
    T: HasFoo,
{
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("default foo");
    }
}

impl HasFoo for String {}
```

We can do the same to your example, by introducing a `trait HasAB`, to trigger a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=blanket#blanket-implementation) of both `A` and `B`:

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee39134754df8d754428f06b0c82a0f0))

```rust
trait HasAB {}

trait A {
    fn a(&self, count: i32) -> String;
}

trait B {
    fn b(&self, count: i32) -> String;
}

impl<T> A for T
where
    T: HasAB + Display,
{
    fn a(&self, count: i32) -> String {
        if count == 0 {
            String::new()
        } else {
            format!("[{}]a{}", self, self.b(count - 1))
        }
    }
}

impl<T> B for T
where
    T: HasAB + Display,
{
    fn b(&self, count: i32) -> String {
        if count == 0 {
            String::new()
        } else {
            format!("[{}]b{}", self, self.a(count - 1))
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just have to do the following, and your example compiles:

```rust
impl HasAB for String {}
```

Additionally, since we lifted the bounds `A: B` and `B: A`. Then you can now `impl A` for types that don't implement `B`, and vice versa. Which you wouldn't be able to do before.

You'll still be able to manually implement each trait. Without forcing that all of them are implemented for all types.

---

Otherwise, when you're dealing with defaults. Then it's common to move the code into separate functions. Like this:

```rust
impl A for Foo {
    fn a(&self, count: i32) -> String {
        default_a_where_b(self, count)
    }
}

fn default_a_where_b<T>(t: &T, count: i32) -> String
where
    T: B + Display,
{
    if count == 0 {
        String::new()
    } else {
        format!("[{}]a{}", t, t.b(count - 1))
    }
}
```

If you want to get rid of the boilerplate, then you could introduce a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_A_where_B {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl A for $t {
            fn a(&self, count: i32) -> String {
                default_a_where_b(self, count)
            }
        }
    };
}
```

*and vice versa for `impl B`.*

Now you simply do:

```rust
impl_A_where_B!(Foo);
```

Since we don't *really* have [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) nor [negative trait bound](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721), then it makes it harder to juggle these cases where we want default implementations and two-way bounds `A: B` `B: A`.

If it's because you want to require that both traits are implemented, then you can specify that bound on a function instead. Then you avoid the cyclic error:

```rust
fn f<T>(t: &T) where T: A + B {}
```

Overall, Rust doesn't really play nicely (yet?) with what you're trying to do. In reality, you might be better off with a completely separate design. However, it is hard to suggest an alternative solution without a more concrete example.

Comment: However, blanket implementations will not be the defaults, I cannot override those for specific types, can I?

Comment: @avysk Depends on what you mean by "override". If you don't want the "defaults" (i.e. blanket implementation of `A` and `B`) for e.g. `String`, then simply remove `impl HasAB for String`. Now you'll be able to do `impl A for String` and `impl B for String`

Comment: I want to be able to define some `MyType`, where `a()` uses default implementation for trait, and `b()` is defined specifically for this type. I cannot just omit `impl HasB for MyType`, because the default implementation of `a()` will not know it can call `b()` on `MyType`. This approach means that either I override everything or nothing. right?

Comment: @avysk I updated the answer to address it

Comment: @vallentin you're right. In fact, I didn't know Rust would allow this kind of circular instance definition, thanks to you I've learned something new :)